# Type of property 'shapeMatched' does not match type of accessor 'setShapeMatched:'

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm developing an iPhone 4 application and I having problems with the class:

```
    @interface Pattern : NSObject {

        int maxNumShapes;
        NSMutableArray* shapes;
        NSMutableArray* shapeMatched;
        CGSize bounds;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableArray* shapes;
    @property (nonatomic, retain, readonly) NSMutableArray* shapeMatched;

    ...
    - (void) setShapeMatched:(ShapeType)type;

@end
```

And its implementation:

```
- (void) setShapeMatched:(ShapeType)type {
    int index = 0;
    if (shapes != nil)
    {
        for(Object2D* obj in shapes)
        {
            if (obj.figure == type)
            {
                [shapeMatched replaceObjectAtIndex:index 
                                        withObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
                obj.withFillColor = YES;
                break;
            }
            else
                index++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following warning:

```
Type of property 'shapeMatched' does not match type of accessor 'setShapeMatched:'
```

How can I fix this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to rename your custom `setShapeMatched:` to something else (like `setMyShapeMatched`). `setShapeMatched:` is already in use as the setter for your declared property.

Comment: You should really give the check to `sidyll` as he/she answered this first.

Answer (score 14):

You method `- (void)setShapeMatched:(ShapeType)type` is probably intended to change something in the `shapeMatched` array, however, its name overwrites the setter of your property for that very same array.

It's unclear, but if you really want to overwrite the setter, the argument must be of type `NSMutableArray *` since that's the type of your property. Otherwise, if you method just do something else, rename it to avoid the collision. `setShapeMatchedType:(ShapeType)t` might be a good option.